# Terraform lock state at the resource level?

Tags: terraform

I have a tf file that has multiple resources/modules in it and it all uses a single remote state file in s3.

I often target specific modules in the tf file.

If I have locking setup does that mean two people can't make changes at the same time even if they are targeting different modules?

From what I read it seems Terraform locks the entire state file. Does it support resource level locking? Docs didn't seem clear to me on this.

Comment: You're right about the whole state file being locked when you run Terraform actions but I have to ask, why do you do things this way rather than split your resources out into separate folders? I can just about understand wanting to apply a specific resource every now and then (although it's a bad habit to be in) but you should feel comfortable applying out the whole folder or you should be splitting it.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, Terraform does lock the whole state file regardless of what resources you're targeting.

The idea behind this implementation is that there may be references between resources. More precisely an event involving one resource (creation/update/destruction) originally may cause other resources to be created/updated/destroyed. So even `apply -target=resource_one.ref_name` may result in changes of other resources. All of that should be presented in `terraform plan` though.

All state operations (incl. locking) are [currently](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/4700a86ee6f29e80a3f3f55b93e90e804d261fdf/backend/remote-state/backend.go#L54-L70) implemented on the [backend](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/index.html) (S3, Consul, TFE, ...) level and the common interface between them isn't as flexible because the common denominator is basically blob of JSON (state file).

If you have two or more independent parts of infrastructure then I'd suggest you to split them apart into either different [workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html) or directories. You can leverage [`terraform state` subcommands](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/index.html) to do the migration after splitting your config files.

You can also use the [`terraform_remote_state` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html) to reference any outputs exposed from any of these parts.

Managing *independent parts* of your infrastructure in a single state file is not something I'd recommend for a couple of reasons:

- It doesn't scale very well. As you begin to add more resources, the time it takes to finish `terraform plan` & `apply` will increase as Terraform has to check current state of each resource.
- All critical Terraform commands have blast radius wider than necessary which makes human errors much scarier. e.g. accident `terraform destroy` will destroy everything, not just one part of your infra.

The `-target` flag is meant to be used for exceptional circumstances, *not* for routine operations, as [mentioned in the docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html#resource-targeting).